# RFID-RC522 not reading some MIFARE Classic 1k cards

Tags: rfid

I am playinig around with RC522 chip that I bought today.
RC522 is connected to arduino Uno.

But I have a weird problem.

I scanned two chinese magic cards that came with the RC522 - and it reads both fine:

```
20:20:17.261 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:20:20.458 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:20:23.655 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:20:24.150 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:20:28.921 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:23:15.504 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:23:16.045 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:23:21.851 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:23:23.472 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:23:28.201 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:28:36.575 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:28:37.115 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:28:37.656 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:36:53.504 -> Card UID:90 25 190 25 
20:38:56.848 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129 
20:38:57.388 -> Card UID:154 103 229 129
```

The spec of these chips are MIFARE Classic 1k ISO 14443-3A, As you can see below. (Both same except serial number)

[image]

So this is all good.

But when I try scanning my companies card, it does not work.
So I also used the same NFC tools to scan my company card and this is what I got:

[image]

So it has exactly the same MIFARE Classic 1k spec, but only the chips that came with the RC522 is able to be scanned by RC522.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the post here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=403541.15 and knowing the risk,
connected RC522 to 5v, and it reads the company card fine.